# Add attribute to XML without POJO modification

Tags: kotlin, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I need to supply shared secret attribute to XML, so I decided to add it without exposing it to my API.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Request")
data class TestRequest(@JacksonXmlText val request: String)
```

Here is example POJO, after serializer it looks like

```
<Request>text</Request>
```

I need to add attribute to it, like

```
<Request secret="foobar">text</Request>
```

I looked to Jackson API and it looks like I need to create custom serializer for root, so

```
class SessionModule: SimpleModule("Test serializer", PackageVersion.VERSION) {

    override fun setupModule(context: SetupContext) {

        context.addBeanSerializerModifier(object : XmlBeanSerializerModifier() {

            override fun modifySerializer(config: SerializationConfig, beanDesc: BeanDescription, serializer: JsonSerializer<*>): JsonSerializer<*> {

                val modifiedSerializer = super.modifySerializer(config, beanDesc, serializer)

                if (modifiedSerializer is XmlBeanSerializer) {
                    println("Registering custom serializer")
                    return SessionFieldSerializer(modifiedSerializer)
                }

                return modifiedSerializer
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And my custom serializer that do nothing

```
class SessionFieldSerializer: XmlBeanSerializer {

    constructor(src: BeanSerializerBase?) : super(src)
    constructor(src: XmlBeanSerializerBase?, objectIdWriter: ObjectIdWriter?, filterId: Any?) : super(src, objectIdWriter, filterId)
    constructor(src: XmlBeanSerializerBase?, objectIdWriter: ObjectIdWriter?) : super(src, objectIdWriter)
    constructor(src: XmlBeanSerializerBase?, toIgnore: MutableSet<String>?) : super(src, toIgnore)

    override fun serialize(bean: Any?, g: JsonGenerator?, provider: SerializerProvider?) {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

So, all it do is throw not-implemented exception, however even if SessionFieldSerializer() getting instantiated ( I see "Registering custom serializer" message), serialize function is not called.

Test code:

```
    val mapper = XmlMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
    mapper.registerModule(SessionModule())
    val request = TestRequest("Foobar")
    val test = mapper.writeValueAsString(request)
    println(test)
```

Am I missing something?